# Is it ok to chop index.php and include files?

Tags: sidebar, headers, include

So in my `index.php` I called `get_header()`, `get_sidebar()` and `get_footer()`. My `index.php` is kind of huge. It is separated into 5 divs more. How do I make it cleaner? Is it safe to chop it to files and include the files?

Comment: why don't you just give it "a chop" first?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can separate your code and markup into multiple files. Be aware of [scope issues when you use include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), but done carefully it should be no problem. Since you are in WordPress and building a theme, I would suggest [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) over a raw `include`.

In many ways, "chopping" up your theme files is what [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is for-- well, at least it is very convenient for that. It lets you separate components of the page and include them in a way that makes easy to extend via child themes.

Comment: Good to know that `get_template_part` is using `require` not `include`.

Comment: @Zlatev : the question asked about `include` so I talked about `include`. Yes, `get_template_part` uses `locate_template` which uses `load_template` which does use `require`, or `require_once`. Given that `locate_template` locates the file before trying to load the file I don't see the significant difference between the two in context. `require` will kill the script, `include` won't, but given that the function never runs unless the file is located it doesn't really matter. You can `get_template_part('nonexistent','template');` all you want and the script just skips right over it.

Comment: Of course. I simply wanted to clarify what QA can expect using `get_template_part` as included files won't inherit variables for example.